# How to get the result of a count quickly?

Tags: java, mysql

I have this query

```
select count(1) from customer 
    inner join supplier on(c_nationkey = s_nationkey);
```

but it is taking a long time in MySQL only.

How can I increase her performance?

Comment: define indexes on c_nationkey and s_nationkey

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding one of the two following indices.  For the first strategy:

```
CREATE INDEX c_idx ON customer (c_nationkey);
```

Or for the second strategy:

```
CREATE INDEX s_idx ON supplier (s_nationkey);
```

Either of these indices, if used, would speed up the join process.  Because you are doing a count query, a full table scan on one or the other table is unavoidable.  But the join can be optimized.

Comment: I had already created the indexes, but it did not greatly improve the performance.

Comment: Well you need at least a single full table scan, there is no way around this.  So, if your tables are large, the query may take some time.